# How to find out dynamic reverse SSH remote port without sudo

Tags: ssh, sshd, reverse-tunnel

I can initialize reverse SSH from client with following command:

```
$ ssh -R 0:localhost:22 <server_host>
Allocated port 42853 for remote forward to localhost:22
```

How can I figure out that 42853 port from the server side without sudo?

Comment: Looking around, somebody had the same issue as you and made a patch (which might now be outdated)  and discusses about other methods: https://nico.schottelius.org/blog/openssh-6.2-add-callback-functionality-using-dynamic-remote-port-forwarding/